# GSutil RSync - Change Max File path limit to match Windows

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a large project that I need to backup using GSutil. I keep getting "Error 3" with files nearing the windows file path limit. Is there anyway to get this working?

I Tried recreating the issue by syncing a diffrent local file with a long path to a diffrent folder. The same error occured.

(console output) https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEGc5.png

I am running Windows 10. 
The command i ran is : gsutil -m rsync -r -d -n Test Target

This is the path which failed:

C:\Users\temp\Desktop\Test\TestPath\LongTestTestTestTestTest Test - LongTestTestTestTestTest Test - LongTestTestTestTestTest Test - LongTestTestTestTestTest Test -\LongTestTestTestTestTest Test\LongTestTestTestTes\SO MUCH LONGER PATH 2\A BIT LONGER AGAIN\LONG FILE NAME,2_1225688.txt

(windows path) https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVRue.png

The issue I have is Windows allows these files to exist but gsutil is unable to sync them. If I shorten the path by a few characters the issue goes away. The Issue occurs during the listing phase It occurs both in the soruce and the target folder.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without the more specific / detailed error message. If you want to avoid posting that info on the public forum you could try sending your question to gs-team@google.com.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Thanks for the reply! I updated the post with relevant information.

Comment: That filename is shorter than the max allowed GCS object name, and all the characters are allowed. Are you sure that's the full windows path, and not just the final pathname component?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz , Ah yes the path i posted was relative to the desktop, I edited in the full path aswell.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Error 3 means path not found. Are you sure the path you're using with gsutil is the same path as you're using with whatever Windows command you used to look at the file? I'm wondering if it's problem with a typo in the path name.

Comment: Yes, its easy to test. if you are trying to sync a file witch path is so long you can no longer add characters to the files name. You can still add characters to the folders name, By doing this you can reach a much longer path name. Trying to sync this gives me error 3. I have not tested exactly at what count it fails. But it fails reliably on a path over 280 characters. 

It would be nice with a option to skip these files with a warning or still being able to sync them, since windows allow them to exist.

Comment: I have tried out rsyncing with this command: gsutil -m rsync -r -d . gs://my-bucket/
A file with a path like this: "/home/myusername/saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii/moreeeeeee
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/ helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.txt "  Which has more characters than yours

Comment: And it synced without error. Have you confirm that the path you are testing out with actually exists and you are able to access to it locally?.

Comment: @Mayeru Did you do this test on a Windows 10 machine? I could not snyc a folder with that path. 
Yes i have confirmed the path exsists. Allthough windows notepad is having trouble opening the file becouse of the length of the path. But windows can copy the file out and read it correctly.

I just tried this at home aswell with the latest version of gsutil. Strangely i gort a diffrent error here: "gsutil ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)"

Same thing if i lower the path by a few characters the error goes away and everything works correctly

Comment: Note: I am trying to sync two local folders, but have also tried syncing from the local folder to my bucket

Comment: I tested it on Linux. Now I have tried with Windows 10, I was able to perform the rsync to my bucket if I run the command directly under the directory "using:  gsutil -m rsync -d . gs://my-bucket/temp/" when specifying the directory address I got the "The rsync command accepts at most 2 arguments"  but that using the example you provided (that I even had to cut a little short because Windows didn't let me create a longer path). The last error you got seems like a encoding issue, gsutil specifies that : "Arguments must be decodable as Unicode", you can read more running "`gsutil help encoding"

Comment: Could you do the test with just letters and no spaces/special characters ?  As long as they can be decodable as Unicode shouldn't be an issue but the fact that you got the "can't decode byte 0xe5" error tells me it could be an encoding issue of the path.  Since it would be weird that gsutil can accept a long path on Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: The path resulting in  "can't decode byte 0xe5" is only letters and no scpace & special characters.

Its the following path:
C:\Users\Nikolai\Desktop\Sync\From2\X\hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\Dataaaa.txt

But if i press properties on the file windows displays the path oddly:
https://i.imgur.com/reZHr3P.png. This seams to only happen when the path gets long.

Comment: We are trying to work around the issue by lowering the path of our project. The project were previously backed up correctly on a Linux Machine but we recently moved to a windows server and that is when the issue appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I found a useful discussion on [Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/232986/overcoming-maximum-file-path-length-restrictions-in-windows) and this simple solution worked on my Windows Server 2016:

Replace

```
gsutil -m rsync -r C:\ gs://...
```

by

```
gsutil -m rsync -r \\?\C:\ gs://...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with UNC paths, e.g. `gsutil -m rsync -r \\?\UNC\server\share gs://...`.